# CMYK colours in a graph template

Tags: plotting, color

Hi I'm trying to put together a graphing template.  Unfortunately, my arrowheads are a different colour than my functions when the graph is exported to something like a PDF.  Is there a way I can manually set the arrowhead colours in CMYK using this setup?  I'd also like to change the function arrowheads to lines instead of enclosed arrows.  Here's the important parts. The arrowheads come from the last line.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Interpretation[{f = {  1/(x - 1) + 1, Sin[x], -x, x}, 
  points = {{3, 2}, {-5, -8}}, min = -10, max = 10, size = 0.5, 
  rmin = -10, rmax = 10, gridx = 1, gridy = 1, hlabel = "x", 
  vlabel = "y"}, 
 Panel[Grid[{{Style["Plot Characteristics", Bold], SpanFromLeft},
    {"Functions:", InputField[Dynamic[f]]}
    }]],

 Plot[f, {x, min - 0.58*gridx, max + 0.58*gridx},

   PlotStyle -> {{AbsoluteThickness[1], 
      CMYKColor[0, 0, 0, 1]}, {AbsoluteThickness[1], 
      CMYKColor[0, 0.83, 1, 0]}, {AbsoluteThickness[1], 
      CMYKColor[1, 0, 0, 0]}, {AbsoluteThickness[1], 
      CMYKColor[0.36, 1, 0, 0]}, {AbsoluteThickness[1], 
      CMYKColor[0.63, 0, 1, 0]}, {AbsoluteThickness[1], 
      CMYKColor[0, 0, 0, 1]}}
      ]
  /. Line[x__] :> Sequence[Arrowheads[{-.02, .02}], Arrow[x]]
 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to change the arrow heads to your preferred style:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Interpretation[{f = {1/(x - 1) + 1, Sin[x], -x, x},
  points = {{3, 2}, {-5, -8}},
  min = -10, max = 10, size = 0.5,
  rmin = -10, rmax = 10,
  gridx = 1, gridy = 1,
  hlabel = "x", vlabel = "y"},
 Panel[Grid[
   {{Style["Plot Characteristics", Bold], SpanFromLeft},
    {"Functions:", InputField[Dynamic[f]]}}]],
 Plot[f, {x, min - 0.58*gridx, max + 0.58*gridx},
   PlotStyle -> {
     {AbsoluteThickness[1], CMYKColor[0, 0, 0, 1]},
     {AbsoluteThickness[1], CMYKColor[0, 0.83, 1, 0]},
     {AbsoluteThickness[1], CMYKColor[1, 0, 0, 0]},
     {AbsoluteThickness[1], CMYKColor[0.36, 1, 0, 0]},
     {AbsoluteThickness[1], CMYKColor[0.63, 0, 1, 0]},
     {AbsoluteThickness[1], CMYKColor[0, 0, 0, 1]}}] /. Line[x__] :>
   Sequence[
    Arrowheads[
     {
      {-.02, 0, Graphics[Line[{{{-1, 1/2}, {0, 0}, {-1, -1/2}}}]]},
      {.02, 1, Graphics[Line[{{{-1, 1/2}, {0, 0}, {-1, -1/2}}}]]}
      }
     ],
    Arrow[x]]]
```

[image: output]

I don't know about the CMYK colors for the arrow heads - I don't see why they should be different from the lines...

Comment: Thanks.  At least half the problem is solved.

Comment: @keystonethewizard You can insert `CMYKColor` calls into the `Graphics[]` expression that draws the arrow-heads...